# Math Contest Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Can somebody help me with this one?  I need to check the answer

Let A denote the set of those 6-digit positive integers in which
each of the digits 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6 appears exactly once. An integer
in A; having standard decimal representation d1d2 : : : d6; is called
nice if for each k = 1; 2; 3; 4; 5, the set fd1; : : : ; dkg contains at
least one digit strictly greater than k (for example, 234561 is nice,
whereas 321645 is not nice). From A; an integer n is randomly
picked. What is the probability that n is nice?

Comment: What is your answer? Can you show your working? THe question could be better phrased, in part because I guess you just copied the text, and so the mathematical statements make less sense.

Comment: You are absoloutely right.  I merely copied the text and hence the confusion.

Comment: Let A denote the set of those 6-digit positive integers in which each of the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 appears exactly once. An integer in A; having standard decimal representation d1,d2 ,,, d6, is called nice if for each k = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 the set (d1,,, dk) contains at least one digit strictly greater than k (for example, 234561 is nice, whereas 321645 is not nice). From A; an integer n is randomly picked. What is the probability that n is nice?

Comment: Run the last digit of the 6-digit number from 1 to 6 and find the combinations as below
23456 1 = 5*4*3*2*1 = 5!
34561 2 = 4*4*3*2*1 = 4*4!
45612 3 = 3*2*3! = 6.3!
56123 4 = 2*1*4! = 2*4!
61234 5 = 1*4! = 4!
12345 6 = 0.
Outcomes = 6!  = 720
Successes = 324
The required probability = 324/720.

Comment: Calvin Lin I reworked the problem and here is my working Run the last digit of the 6 digit number from 1 to 6 and find the combination as below 23456 1 = 5*4*3*2*1 = 5! 34561 2 = 4*4*3*2*1 = 4*4! 45612 3 = 3*4! 56123 4 = 2*4! 61234 5 = 1*4! 12345 6 = 0 Successes = 360 Outcomes = 6! = 720 Required probability = 360/720 = 1/2 Let me know if this is correct!! Thanks Satish